# dc.js compatibility with v4 of d3.js

Tags: d3.js, dc.js

Version 4.x of `d3.js`, which is not backward compatible, came out end of June16.

The bower.json for `dc.js` includes:

```
"dependencies": {
  "d3": "3.x",
  "crossfilter2": "~1.3"
}
```

which explicitly requires v3 (not higher) of `d3.js`.

Is `dc.js` currently compatibility with version 4.x of `d3.js`? If not, is this planned?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's definitely **not** compatible.  `d3` v4 has breaking api changes.

As far as plans go, there's a lively discussion about this on dc.js' [github acount](https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/issues/1173):

> So what is the plan then? Use @jfsiii suggetion of finishing off dc v2
>   using d3 v3 and then create dc v3 using d3 v4? Would upgrading to d3
>   v4 warrant an almost complete re-write?

---

> **gordonwoodhull**:  Something like that. ... I doubt it's a rewrite as there are a lot of subtle details to the way the code is now. Of course if you want to write dc.js from scratch, no one's stopping you, but I'd rather see this repo evolve... Many chart libraries have died from trying to change everything at once.

Comment: Point being that it's a port and probably not a total rewrite. Having read more, I don't think it's going to be all that hard, but getting 2.0 out of beta is my priority. Also I want to learn more about how to structure the library to take advantage of better modularization.