# Will / when will DC.js support D3v4?

Tags: dc.js, d3.js

I've switched to D3v4 but I think DC.js requires D3 v3.5. I've tried it with v4 and it throws an error. Can anyone from the DC world confirm that DC does not currently work with V4 - and any ideas on whether and when this will happen would be a bonus. Thanks.

Comment: dc.js depends on D3v3. I don't see that changing any time soon, as rewriting to v4 would be a fairly significant undertaking, but maybe someone with more involvement like Gordon will comment. I think, however, that you could use D3v4 in the same page as dc.js.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [dc.js compatibility with v4 of d3.js](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38282513/dc-js-compatibility-with-v4-of-d3-js)

Comment: I am studying the differences between v3 and v4, which are extensive but not unsurmountable. I hope to port dc.js at some point but I don't have immediate plans. It's a pretty big task.