# how to properly install dc.js for using with Rails 5?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, node.js, d3.js, dc.js, crossfilter

I am exploring dc.js which would provide great feature to my data quality analysis application. But I am getting crazy about how to setup the libraries to get it fully operational:

- D3 is installed thanks to the d3-rails gem
- Installation of dc.js with **npm install dc** simply returns dc@2.1.6 ../../../node_modules/dc, but brings no feature.
- Referencing dc.js by

  ```
  <script src="https://dc-js.github.io/dc.js/js/crossfilter.js"
  ```

  et

  ```
  <script src="https://dc-js.github.io/dc.js/js/dc.js"></script>
  ```

generates errors such as d3.time is undefined. (does dc only relies on D3 3.x ?).

- Would http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/dc/2.0.0/dc.min.js and 
  http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/dc/2.0.0/dc.min.css provide an up-to-date code ? But what happens if I need it on premises behind a firewall ?
- Should I download and copy all the libraries locally ?

Finally, which is the clean, lean recommended way of implementing dc.js ?

Thanks.

Comment: As I commented in your other question, there is no one clean lean recommended way of dealing with modules in Javascript - there are lots and lots of solutions and a lot of vehement opinions about them. I agree with @davcs86 that the old way, setting up scripts to copy Javascript files out of `node_modules` into the deployment directory (e.g. with grunt or make), is probably the easiest to grok, even though it requires manual configuration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. dc.js is only fully compatible with [d3 v3](https://github.com/d3/d3/releases/tag/v3.5.17), more info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38282513/dc-js-compatibility-with-v4-of-d3-js) and [here](https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/issues/1173).
2. IMHO, the easiest way is the old-school one (copy the libraries locally).

   2.1. Cloudflare doesn't provide the up-to-date code since you asks a specific version in the URL (in your case, 2.0.0).